# Rounding prices and quantities for limit orders on Binance

Tags: c#, binance

When creating a limit order on Binance, especially while adding take profit/stop loss percentages or calculating quantity, it's mandatory to round the price and quantity based on the filters available in the exchange information API endpoint. Otherwise the create limit order endpoint would fail. This is detailed in the following article: https://sammchardy.github.io/binance-order-filters/.

My concern is with the implementation of rounding. For instance, the `ClampPrice` method in the Binance.Net library (https://github.com/JKorf/Binance.Net/blob/master/Binance.Net/BinanceHelpers.cs) seems to just apply a basic min-max approach, which doesn't appear entirely accurate to me.

I made an extension method that in my opinion is more correct. For prices, I round based on the tick size (`BinanceSymbolPriceFilter.TickSize`), and for quantities, I use the step size (`BinanceSymbolLotSizeFilter.StepSize`).

```cs
public static class BinanceHelpers
{
    public static decimal RoundStepSize(decimal priceOrQuantity, decimal stepSize) => priceOrQuantity - priceOrQuantity % stepSize;
}
```

I need to confirm the correctness or completeness of my approach from a trustworthy source, such as the official Binance API documentation.

---

Here are the filters for BTC/USDT that the exchange information endpoint returns:

```
Filters = {BinanceSymbolFilter[]} BinanceSymbolFilter[9]
 [0] = BinanceSymbolPriceFilter
  FilterType = {SymbolFilterType} Price
  MaxPrice = {Decimal} 1000000.00000000
  MinPrice = {Decimal} 0.01000000
  TickSize = {Decimal} 0.01000000
 [1] = BinanceSymbolLotSizeFilter
  FilterType = {SymbolFilterType} LotSize
  MaxQuantity = {Decimal} 9000.00000000
  MinQuantity = {Decimal} 0.00001000
  StepSize = {Decimal} 0.00001000
 [2] = BinanceSymbolIcebergPartsFilter
  FilterType = {SymbolFilterType} IcebergParts
  Limit = {int} 10
 [3] = BinanceSymbolMarketLotSizeFilter
  FilterType = {SymbolFilterType} MarketLotSize
  MaxQuantity = {Decimal} 114.12693879
  MinQuantity = {Decimal} 0.00000000
  StepSize = {Decimal} 0.00000000
 [4] = BinanceSymbolTrailingDeltaFilter
  FilterType = {SymbolFilterType} TrailingDelta
  MaxTrailingAboveDelta = {int} 2000
  MaxTrailingBelowDelta = {int} 2000
  MinTrailingAboveDelta = {int} 10
  MinTrailingBelowDelta = {int} 10
 [5] = BinanceSymbolPercentPriceBySideFilter
  AskMultiplierDown = {Decimal} 0.2
  AskMultiplierUp = {Decimal} 5
  AveragePriceMinutes = {int} 5
  BidMultiplierDown = {Decimal} 0.2
  BidMultiplierUp = {Decimal} 5
  FilterType = {SymbolFilterType} PercentagePriceBySide
 [6] = BinanceSymbolNotionalFilter
  ApplyMaxToMarketOrders = {bool} false
  ApplyMinToMarketOrders = {bool} true
  AveragePriceMinutes = {int} 5
  FilterType = {SymbolFilterType} Notional
  MaxNotional = {Decimal} 9000000.00000000
  MinNotional = {Decimal} 5.00000000
 [7] = BinanceSymbolMaxOrdersFilter
  FilterType = {SymbolFilterType} MaxNumberOrders
  MaxNumberOrders = {int} 200
 [8] = BinanceSymbolMaxAlgorithmicOrdersFilter
  FilterType = {SymbolFilterType} MaxNumberAlgorithmicOrders
  MaxNumberAlgorithmicOrders = {int} 5
```

Comment: "doesn't appear entirely accurate to me."  Why?  Do you have examples that fail using that code but work with yours?  I looks to me like you're doing a lot of assuming.

Comment: @TimRobers because we need to round the price to the 2nd decimal point for BTC.

Comment: Where do you see any mention of that?  BTC quantities are commonly specified to 8 or 9 decimal places.

Comment: @TimRoberts for front end visualization purposes it doesn't make sense to display 8 decimal places.

Comment: Why not?  If I want to sell 0.0012 BTC, which is not uncommon, how are you going to represent that?  And your question said it is "mandatory".  Where do you see that it is mandatory?  I think your requirements are confused.

Comment: @TimRoberts 0.0012 BTC is _quantity_, not a _price_. What I'm saying is _prices_ should be rounded based on `BinanceSymbolPriceFilter.TickSize` (`0.01000000` for BTC) and _quantities_ based on `BinanceSymbolLotSizeFilter.StepSize` (`0.00001000`)